# Custom Object Initialization in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I created a custom object in Objective-C. Now I want to create a custom initializer. The object has two properties, name and score. So my initializer is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)playerName {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.name = [playerName retain];
        self.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Am I using **`retain`** here properly? Or can I just make it something like `self.name = playerName;`?

Furthermore, assume I want another initializer, but keep the `initWithName:playerName` the designated initializer. How would I make the second initializer call the first?

And for the last question, I know I need to override the `- (id)init` method too. However, what do I do there? Just assign test properties incase the class was initialized with `init` only?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I using retain here properly?

No you are not.  You should either use

```
self.name = playerName;
```

as you suggested, or (as recommended by Apple)

```
name = [playerName copy];
```

It is not recommended to use accessors in `-init` because subclasses might override them.

Also, note that as `NSString` implements `NSCopying` you should use a copy property, not a retain property.

> Furthermore, assume I want another initializer, but keep the initWithName:playerName the designated initializer. How would I make the second initializer call the first?

Using `-init` as an example (because you **must** override the super class's designated initialiser if your designated initialiser is not the same)

```
-(id) init
{
    return [self initWithName: @"Some default value"];
}
```

Comment: Regarding `NSString` implementing `NSCopying`, so `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString ...` would be wrong? I should substitute retain with copy? If so, then I should not release it in `dealloc` correct?

Comment: @Nayefc: `@property (copy) NSString*` is right for a `NSString` property (`nonatomic` is optional of course).  You still need to release it in `dealloc` because you own objects obtained with `copy`.

Answer (score 2):

you could keep `self.name = playerName;` if you have declared `name` as retained property in **.h** class and have also `@synthesized` in **.m** file.

For the initialization you could put the belwo two line of code in separate method.

```
-(void) initializeWithName:(NSString*) aName withNumber:(int) aNumber
{
  self.name = aName;
  self.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:aNumber];
}
```

Lets you have three Initialization  method.

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)playerName {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
      [self initializeWithName:playerName withNumber:0]
    }

    return self;
}


- (id)initWithNumber:(int*) aNumber {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
       [self initializeWithName:nil withNumber:aNumber]
    }

    return self;
}


- (id)init{

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self initializeWithName:nil withNumber:0]
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For what's it's worth to the rest of us newbies:

In normal languages, can simply define arguments when instantiating the class:

```
public final class MakeBed {

    private var foo:Object;
    public var bar:Array;

    public function MakeBed(_foo:Object, _bar:Array) {
        // Do stuff
        foo = _foo;
        bar = _bar;
    }

}
```

Then when we want to instantiate the class it's as simple as:

```
var myBeadMaker:MakeBed = new MakeBed({}, []);
```

---

**In objc everything is backasswards.**

You can create your custom initializer similar to:

```
// These @properties go into the header.h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *foo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bar;

// This is in your implimentation.m file
- (id) initWithInfo:(NSObject*)foo withBar:(NSArray *)bar {
    _foo = foo;
    _bar = bar;
}
```

Objc automatically "synthesizes" the getters and setters and automatically creates a new variable "blindly" using the same _name _but _with _an _underscore in front when you do the @property thing -- it's magic -- bordering on the "almost too helpful" side of things.

Handy for non-newbies, but incredibly confusing for newbies -- just believe that the getter and setter is made and that a _new _var _is _available.

And the clincher that everyone forgets to mention...

When you want to instantiate the class with your custom initializer you do this:

```
MakeBed myBedMaker = [[MakeBed alloc] initWithInfo:*foo withBar:*bar];
```

Comment: that `initWithInfo:withBar:` method is really wrong. It doesn't call super and doesn't return anything!

Comment: You have defined `foo` and `bar` as strings but use assign an `NSObject` and an `NSArray` to them. (Also bad practice to use retain/strong for classes that have mutable subclasses (like strings and arrays for example))

Comment: `[[MakeBed alloc] initWithInfo:*foo withBar:*bar]` is also wrong. You pass the arguments as `initWithInfo:foo withBar:bar`. All these things are *basic* Objective-C.

Comment: -1. You really miss some basic concepts of the language to afford to do a comparative analysis with anything.

Comment: By the way, when you approach a language you should its basic construct first. "*Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance variable will be called _firstName.*" This is taken from Apple doc and it's pretty visible.